# Symfony Form CollectionType, get the value of the active entry in entry_options

Tags: forms, symfony-forms, symfony

In Symfony, I have a function `buildForm()` in an `AbstractType` extended Class, I use a `CollectionType`, and I want, to get the value of the active entry inside the `entry_options` array:

Here's my code:

```
  if($options['data']->getDescription()->isEmpty()){
      $options['data']->getDescription()->set('fr',null);
      $options['data']->getDescription()->set('en',null);
   }

   $builder->add('description',CollectionType::class,array(
     'label'=>'MyBundle.messages.description',
      'entry_type'=>TextType::class,
      'entry_options'=>array(
          'label'=>'JCABundle.messages.language_name.'.[active entry value]
      )
   ));
```

My wish is to get [active entry value] substituted by 'fr' or 'en', knowing that 'description' (The attribute of the entity I use with my form) is an ArrayCollection that contains 'fr and 'en'.

So it could display correctly: 'Français', 'Anglais' or 'French', 'English' instead of 'fr', 'en' as a label.

Any idea?

Comment: If you need clean access to a form entity from buildForm() then you need to use an event subscriber: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html.  Bit of a pain but that is the way forms were designed.  You could probably use a twig extension to clean up your twig approach.

Comment: `CollectionType` can't handle dynamic entry options for now. The event listener on a custom type is the way to go.

Comment: @Heah, @Cerad, Ok I guess you go then with  `$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,function($event){...` but in the listener, how do you get the value of the element of the CollectionType and use it to alter the 'label' attribute?

Comment: You should not use `CollectionType` but a custom type then loop through the data in a `POST_SET_DATA` event to add the fields dynamically.

Comment: OK I think I got the idea, I'll keep my TWIG hack for the moment. SYMFONY.... it does a lot but should do more :)

Comment: You don't alter the label instead you add the description element in your subscriber with whatever label you need.  The form component works fine for a reasonable number of use cases but does not do well once you go outside it's box.

Comment: @Cerad, sorry I don't figure out the direction you're pointing me to in your last comment. The meaning of "add the description element in your subscriber" is blur to me.

Comment: Think I'll have to bow out here.  I really have no idea what you mean by "active entry value".  I assumed that description was an array of something (hence the form collection) but maybe not.

Comment: My `Entity` linked to `class EntityType extends AbstractType` has an attribute `description` which is an `ArrayCollection` (and keys in that ArrayCollection are language code: 'fr','en'). I thought that when we put an `ArrayCollection`  in a `CollectionType`, there could be a match so that when I go in the `entry_option`, i would access each key element of the ArrayCollection. Because afterall, if I do nothing, the labels I get in the HTML final result are 'en' and 'fr', which are the keys of my ArrayCollection. Does it make sense?

Comment: So for each description you want to have a text input element and you want to be able to control the label for each element?  In that case, write your own DescriptionType then use a subscriber on it to get the actual value of each description and customize.  The options data lines are still confusing.  You should probably initialize your entity before passing it to the form.

Comment: Yes we're on the same page. I won't investigate further on custom `****Type` creation with `EventListener` on top of it for the moment. Got to go forward with my project so TWIG solution will do. But thanks for the tips, it helps to understand better SYMFONY to get others' point of view.

Comment: @Cerad, I ve finally followed your tip and posted the solution, thanks, sorry I don't know how to make you earn more points on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution according to the comments posted, advising me to use **EventListener on a custom ***Type**:

I created a new Type (NB: TexareaType could be switch with TextType):

```
   <?php
    namespace MyBundle\Form\Type;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;


    class MultilangTextareaType extends AbstractType
    {

      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {

            $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
                function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();

                   $mlta = $form->getViewData();
                    foreach($mlta as $mltaK => $mltaV){
                        $formOptions = array(
                            'label' => 'MyBundle.messages.language_name.'.$mltaK,
                            'constraints'=>array()
                        ); 

                        $form->add($mltaK, TextareaType::class, $formOptions);
                    }
                }
            );

      }


        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array());
        }

        public function getParent()
        {
            return CollectionType::class;
        }

        public function getBlockPrefix(){
            return 'multilang_textarea';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Then my initial code in the `buildForm()` becomes:

```
  if($options['data']->getDescription()->isEmpty()){
      $options['data']->getDescription()->set('fr',null);
      $options['data']->getDescription()->set('en',null);
    }

    $builder->add('description',MultilangTextareaType::class,array(
     'label'=>'MyBundle.messages.description'
    );
```